# click on img capybara

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

Git this page https://ru.aliexpress.com/store/product/Original-xiaomi-Redmi-note3-snapdragon-650-4000mAh-13ML-1080P-3G-32G-5-5-screen-octa-core/1986585_32622877163.html?detailNewVersion=&categoryId=5090301
and i need to click on each color modification as i think. All configs and driver works fine cuz` other elements on page i can interact.

Code

```
page.all(:css, '.item-sku-image img').each_with_index do |mod,i|

      find(:xpath,"//img[@title='#{mod['title']}']").find(:xpath, "..").click

      puts find(:xpath,"//img[@title='#{mod['title']}']").find(:xpath, "..").find(:xpath, "..")['class'] # with this line i'm checkin` if i clicked on img block cuz his parend node changes it's class to active
    end
```

Have no idea why can i click on every single item or link on this page except this block of img. ( using poltergeist )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to refind the element, and in fact it should be perfectly fine to click the img element itself.

```
page.all(:css, '.item-sku-image img').each_with_index do |mod,i|
  mod.click # mod.find(:xpath, "./..").click if you do need to click the parent
  puts mod.find(:xpath, "./ancestor::li").matches_selector?(:css, '.active')
end
```